# Replacing extrordinarily slow pow() function

Tags: c, fortran, libc, pow

We have a CFD solver and while running a simulation, it was found to run extraordinarily slow on some machines but not others. Using Intel VTune, it was found the following line was the problem (in Fortran):

```
RHOV= RHO_INF*((1.0_wp - COEFF*EXP(F0)))**(1.0_wp/(GAMM - 1.0_wp))
```

Drilling in with VTune, the problem was traced to the `call pow` assembly line and when tracing the stack, it showed it was using `__slowpow()`. After some searching, [this page](http://entropymine.com/imageworsener/slowpow/) showed up complaining about the same thing.

On the machine with libc version 2.12, the simulation took 18 seconds. On the machine with libc version 2.14, the simulation took 0 seconds.

Based on the information on the aforementioned page, the problem arises when the base to `pow()` is close to 1.0. So we did another simple test where we scaled the base by an arbitrary number before the `pow()` and then divided by the number raised to the exponent after the `pow()` call. This dropped the runtime from 18 seconds to 0 seconds with the libc 2.12 also.

However, it's impractical to put this all over the code where we do `a**b`. How would one go about replacing the `pow()` function in libc? For instance, I would like the assembly line `call pow` generated by the Fortran compiler to call a custom `pow()` function we write that does the scaling, calls the libc `pow()` and then divides by the scaling. How does one create an intermediate layer transparent to the compiler?

**Edit**

To clarify, we're looking for something like (pseudo-code):

```
double pow(a,b) {
   a *= 5.0
   tmp = pow_from_libc(a,b)
   return tmp/pow_from_libc(5.0, b)
}
```

Is it possible to load the `pow` from libc and rename it in our custom function to avoid the naming conflicts? If the `customPow.o` file could rename `pow` from libc, what happens if libc is still needed for other things? Would that cause a naming conflict between `pow` in `customPow.o` and `pow` in libc?

Comment: Good ol' Fortran! Interesting question though +1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just write your own `pow` function, put the `.o` file in a static library archive `libmypow.a` somewhere in the linker's library path, and pass `-lmypow` when linking.

Comment: Would that allow the custom `pow` function to call `pow` in libc though? This custom `pow` will just scale the base if needed, then call libc `pow` and then unscale if needed. It seems like there would be some naming conflicts.

Comment: If you use dynamic linking, there are `dlsym` hacks you can use to achieve the desired behavior, but it's fragile. A better approach, if you only need it to work on systems with the GNU linker, is the `--wrap` option to `ld` (which `gcc` can pass to `ld` via `-Wl,--wrap,pow`). You then put `__wrap_pow` in `libmypow.a`, and make it call `__real_pow` where it needs to use the libc pow, and all should be well.

Answer (score 24):

Well, hold on now.  The library isn't calling `__slowpow()` just to toy with you; it's calling `__slowpow()` because it believes the extra precision is necessary to give an accurate result for the values you're giving it (in this case, base very near 1, exponent of order 1).   If you care about the accuracy of this computation, you should understand why that is and if it matters before trying to work around it.   It might be the case that for (say) large negative F0 this whole thing can be safely rounded to 1; or it might not, depending on what's done with this value later.  If you ever need 1.d0 minus this result, you're going to want that extra precision.

Comment: That's certainly true. But, at least in our instance, our code is dimensional so the only times we have a base near one is when computing things for visualization or post processing of some sort, so getting within 1e-15 of the right answer isn't terribly important. I ran a comparison to see how much we lose and the error is ~1e-13, which for our second order accurate code is smaller than our discretization error anyway so it's safe for us to replace all pow() with a slightly less accurate one.

Answer (score 4):

`pow(a,b)` is the same as `exp(b*ln(a))`, maybe that substitution will work for you.

Comment: That would likely circumvent the slowness of the call, but we're looking for a way to essentially replace the function call generated by the `**` operator in Fortran without having to change the actual codebase we have, if possible.

Comment: So link your own version of pow() that uses this identity.

Comment: this gives a different result for 1.0000000000000020^1.5: 1.0000000000000031 with `call pow`, 1.0000000000000029 with `-ffast-math` and 1.5000000000000013 with `exp(b*ln(a))`

Answer (score 1):

I tested this myself, and indeed if I compile the test program from the page you link to it uses `call pow` in the assembly code.  However, compiling with optimization `-ffast-math` there is no call to pow, but the result is slightly different.